# Resources for travelling around the world without flying

Tags: around-the-world

Are there any good resources for travelling around the world without flying?

Looking for blogs, books, YouTube uploaders, etc.

I would like to start from and return to Australia, going through Asia first.

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is "overland". We have a bunch of questions about this: [tag:overland], and also questions about [tag:trains], [tag:freighter-travel], [tag:ferries], etc.

Comment: A few relevant guide books: Bradt's *Africa Overland*, Lonely Planet's *Trans-Siberian Railway*, Insight Guides' *The Silk Road*, The Rough Guide *First Time Around the World* (the last one is not specifically about overland travel, however).

Comment: Thanks guys, @Relaxed I will definitely look in to reading some of those books. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would most definitely start with [The Man in Seat 61](http://www.seat61.com/Australia-overland.htm), I linked you the Europe to Australia without flying page.

Comment: Terrific, the train itinerary that he suggests through se Asia is great. I am familiar with the transiberian, but didn't know about catching local trains from Singapore to Beijing. This works perfectly considering you can sail from Darwin to Singapore with the Sail Indonesia rally.

Comment: The next parts I'll need to figure out are crossing the Atlantic and then the Pacific oceans.